# DOMParser adding child styles to parent when converting html string to html document

Tags: xml, dom, domparser

I am getting contents of tinyMCE as html then i am converting the html to some custom xml.

I first create html document using this

```
parser.parseFromString(htmlTxt, "text/html");
```

where parser is an instance of DOMParser

but the parent element is taking the child styles.

For example the html string below

```
<p><span style="font-family: 'Arial Unicode MS'; font-size: 50px;">dddfdfdf<span style="font-size: 36px;">df</span></span></p>
```

is being converted as

```
<p><span style="font-family: &quot;Arial Unicode MS&quot;; font-size: 36px;">dddfdfdf<span style="font-size: 36px;">df</span></span></p>
```

the font size of child is being applied to parent.

How can i prevent this ?

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Does DOMParser have a bug reporting system?

Comment: You mean an error handler ? The error i have seen it throw is when there is malformed string

Comment: Any help is welcome. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this by getting the htmldocument directly from tinymce instead of html string so i dont have to use the DomParser. Thanks all for the assistance.